# Why multiple save pop up box appear?

Tags: php, jspdf, jquery-selectbox

I draw chart using google chart. The chart is displayed using select box.

[image]

Then the button save as pdf will pop up save as dialog box to save the image in pdf format.

This is the code:

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawCategoryNameChart); 
function drawCategoryNameChart(){

                // for category-filter
                $('#category_filter').on('change',function(){
                var select1 = $(this).val();  // category-filter value
                var jsonCategoryNameData = $.ajax({
                            url: "<?php echo $ajaxurl11; ?>",
                            contentType: "application/json",
                            data: {Value1 : select1},
                            dataType: "json",
                            async: false
                            }).responseText;



                var CategoryNameData = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonCategoryNameData);

                var optionsCategoryNameChart = {
                             //title: 'Job/Internship Distribution by Category',
                             titleTextStyle: {
                                  color: 'Black',
                                  fontSize: 18
                                },
                                pieSliceText: 'none',
                             fontSize: '11',
                             hAxis: {
                                  title: 'Category Name',
                                },
                             vAxis: {
                                  title: 'Total',
                                  minValue: 0,
                                  gridlines: { count: 4 }       
                                },
                             legend: {textStyle: {color: '#464847', fontSize: 11}},
                             tooltip: {isHtml: true},
                             backgroundColor: '#F8F9FA',
                             colors: [ '#3B84BB', '#FFAF45', '#FFE345', '#0CAA63', '#1D40A6', '#F7AE12', '#F75012','#6944C3'],
                             chartArea: {
                                    backgroundColor: {
                                        stroke: '#fff',
                                        strokeWidth: 1
                                    }
                                },
                             height: 300,
                             chartArea: { left:"10%",top:"20%",width:"70%",height:"50%" }
                              };        


                // Instantiate and draw our pie chart, passing in some options.
                var CategoryNameChart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('categoryname_chart_div'));

                //draw the chart      
                CategoryNameChart.draw(CategoryNameData, optionsCategoryNameChart);

                google.visualization.events.addListener(CategoryNameChart, 'ready', function () {
                   btnSave.disabled = false;
                });

                var btnSave = document.getElementById('pdf-categoryname');

                btnSave.addEventListener('click', function () {
                    var doc = new jsPDF();
                    doc.setFontSize(15);
                    doc.text(70, 25, "Job & Internship by Category");
                    doc.addImage(CategoryNameChart.getImageURI(), 15, 30);
                    doc.setFontSize(9);
                    doc.text(50, 115, "The bar chart shows the category of job & Internship posted by linked companies");
                    doc.save('category_name.pdf');
                  }, false);

             });
    }
```

The chart is displayed in this code;

```
<div class="chart-3-5block-inner">
                            <div class="chart-block-title">Job & Internship by Category</div>
                            <div class="chart-view" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 10px">

                                <!-- //combo box options to select application filter -->
                                <?php
                                     echo 'Category Group: ';
                                     echo '<select id="category_filter">';
                                     echo '<option value="0" selected="selected">Select</option>';
                                     echo '<option value="1">Accounting/Finance</option>';
                                     echo '<option value="2">Admin/Human Resources</option>';
                                     echo '<option value="3">Arts/Media/Communications</option>';
                                     echo '<option value="4">Building/Construction</option>';
                                     echo '<option value="5">Computer/Information Technology</option>';
                                     echo '<option value="6">Education/Training</option>';
                                     echo '<option value="7">Engineering</option>'; 
                                     echo '</select>';

                                ?>

                            </div>                  
                            <div class="chart-view" id="categoryname_chart_div"></div>
                            <div class="chart-block-description">The bar chart shows the category of job & Internship posted by linked companies</div>
                            <div class="chart-block-view">
                                <input id="pdf-categoryname" type="button" value="Save as PDF" disabled />
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

However, the save as pdf button got problem. When the select box is selected many times, multiple pop up box will appear when the save as button is clicked. 2 times clicked, 2 pop up box appear. It saves the image of all previous selected chart. How to make it appear only once although the select box selected few times?

If I put the btnSave function outside the onchange function, then it cannot read CategoryNameChart. How to take the value of CategoryNameChart in the onchange function so that btnSave can take the value and use it?

This is example jsfiddle to play with. But it is still not fully working. I include dummy data inside for example, so need to adjust a little bit.

https://jsfiddle.net/5aprn44f/3/

Comment: I am not that familiar with jquery but is there a way where you say like if keypressdown end or something

Comment: Check you're not calling `drawCategoryNameChart()` twice.

Comment: I don't call twice

Comment: is it because of the on change function

Comment: any idea what is miscoded?

Comment: Deleted my answer: no reason to go further inspecting bugs/incorrect behaviours without a fiddle or something similar. Can you provide a fiddle to us to play with?

Comment: ok. I'll try to update with a fiddle later..Thanks

Comment: I just put inside example jsfiddle but not fully working, could you help using the fiddle? thanks